# How to Automatically generate GUID in asp.net mvc4 form while insert data to Db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How to Automatically generate GUID in asp.net mvc4 form while insert data to Db

i need to add GUID data type to my table and need to insert automatically 16bit value while submit other data

Comment: What data access are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following link..

[Using a GUID as the ID in a database with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302267/using-a-guid-as-the-id-in-a-database-with-asp-net-mvc)

I think your problem might be solved.

Comment: Thanks hasib it will really help me